# Error Parsing XML cant seem to find invalid token

Tags: android, xml

I can't seem to find where I went wrong in this xml. Can anyone see why I am getting an invalid token error?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

<EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/edit_message">
</EditText>

</LinearLayout>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Try adding `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` before `LinearLayout` tag

Comment: Did you put `</LinearLayout>` at the end?

Comment: @pelya Yes, sorry! It wasn't indented enough to see in the post.

Comment: @MarcoDufal I added that line, if it helps it seems it says the error is on the line `android:orientation="horizontal"`